# C# StretchBlt to copy between two Bitmaps draws nothing

Tags: c#, windows, gdi+, gdi

### tl;dr;

I'm trying to use the following code to copy and stretch part of my `srcBmp` bitmap into my `destBmp` using `StretchBlt` - it's returning `1` indicating success, but there's nothing drawn on the destination bitmap...

```cs
    public static void StretchBltImage()
    {
        // create the source bitmap
        var srcBmp = new Bitmap(500, 500, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        var srcGfx = Graphics.FromImage(srcBmp);
        srcGfx.Clear(Color.Green);
        var srcHdc = srcGfx.GetHdc();

        // create the target image
        var destBmp = new Bitmap(200, 200, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using var destGfx = Graphics.FromImage(destBmp);
        destGfx.Clear(Color.Gray);
        var destHdc = destGfx.GetHdc();

        var res1 = SetStretchBltMode(destHdc, STRETCH_HALFTONE);
        var res2 = StretchBlt(destHdc, 75, 75, 50, 50, srcHdc, 0, 0, 100, 100, SRCCOPY);

        srcGfx.ReleaseHdc(srcHdc);
        destGfx.ReleaseHdc(destHdc);
        destBmp.Save(".\\image.png");
    }
```

### Long Version

I'm writing a C# application which **successfully** uses `StretchBlt` to capture (and shrink) a portion of the desktop into a Bitmap image with the following (simplified) code.

**ConsoleApp1.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="System.Drawing.Common" Version="8.0.0-preview.5.23280.5" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Capture.cs**

```cs
public static partial class Capture
{
    [LibraryImport("user32")]
    internal static partial nint GetDesktopWindow();

    [LibraryImport("user32")]
    internal static partial nint GetWindowDC(nint hWnd);

    [LibraryImport("gdi32")]
    internal static partial int SetStretchBltMode(
        nint hdc,
        int mode);

    [LibraryImport("gdi32")]
    internal static partial int StretchBlt(nint hdcDest, int xDest, int yDest, int  , int hDest, nint hdcSrc, int xSrc, int ySrc, int wSrc, int hSrc, int rop);

    private const int BLACKNESS = 0x00000042;
    private const int SRCCOPY = 0x00CC0020;
    private const int STRETCH_HALFTONE = 4;

    public static void StretchBltScreen()
    {
        // open the desktop handles
        var srcHwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
        var srcHdc = GetWindowDC(srcHwnd);

        // create the target image
        var destBmp = new Bitmap(200, 200, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        using var destGfx = Graphics.FromImage(destBmp);
        destGfx.Clear(Color.Gray);
        var destHdc = destGfx.GetHdc();

        var res1 = SetStretchBltMode(destHdc, STRETCH_HALFTONE);
        var res2 = StretchBlt(destHdc, 75, 75, 50, 50, srcHdc, 0, 0, 100, 100, SRCCOPY);

        destGfx.ReleaseHdc(destHdc);
        destBmp.Save(".\\screen.png");
    }
}
```

---

**Aside:** The reason I'm using `StretchBlt` is that I'm copying a large portion of an ultra-wide monitor (5120 x 1440) into a small thumbnail, so I don't want to use `Graphics.CopyFromScreen` to copy a full-size image and *then* scale it down - I'd rather do it in one step with `StretchBlt` as it's a lot faster from timings I've taken.

---

So, if I call my `StretchBltScreen` in the main program it works and saves an image like this:

[image]

However, I'm now trying to write some unit tests and I'd like to perform the `StretchBlt` against a static in-memory bitmap rather than use the current desktop as the source, but there's *something* not quite right - `StretchBlt` returns `1` indicating success, but there's nothing drawn on the target thumbnail.

My unit test version looks like the code at the top of this question, and gives this image as a result, with nothing drawn from the source bitmap:

[image]

I'm pretty sure it's got something to do with Device Contexts, Compatible Bitmaps, DIBs, etc and tried various combinations of GDI calls o try to work around this, but at this point I'm a bit stuck on where to go next.

If anyone has any insights I'd be very grateful...